# How to hide graph bottom labels in HorizontalBarChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to hide the bottom labels from the HorizontalBarChart graph (in black border) using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).
I tried `setDrawLabels(false)` for `XAxis, YAxis left, YAxis right` with no success.

[image]

What parameter should i change and set to false to hide this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work when i disable the axis right from my horizontal bar chart.

```
        // Right Y Axis
        YAxis yr = chart.getAxisRight();
        yr.setEnabled(false);
//        yr.setDrawGridLines(false);
//        yr.setDrawAxisLine(false);
//        yr.disableGridDashedLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
XAxis xl = chart.getXAxis();

//This will stop the grid lines from being drawn 
xl.setDrawGridLines(false);

//This Will stop the labels from being drawn
xl.setDrawLabels(false);
```